# How to get the response header in a RestEasy client?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

i´m implementing a Restful service using Jax-RS 2.0 ([Resteasy 3.0.7.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html)) and share the interface between client and service.

The return value is void because ClientResponse is deprecated since RestEasy introduced JAX-RS 2.0 in version 3+.

To return the location of the new created object i inject the response, using the `@Context` annotation, and add the Content-Location header.

For example:

Shared Interface:

```
   @Path("/")
   @Consumes("application/xml")
   @Produces("application/xml")
   interface Resource {

        @Path("createSomething")
        void createSomething(AnyObject object);

        ...
   }
```

Implementation class (The Service):

```
    class ResourceImpl {

         ...
         @Context org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse response;
         ...

         @Override
         void createSomething(AnyObject object) throws AnyException {

             String id = service.create(object);

             response.getOutputHeaders().putSingle("Content-Location",
                  "/createSomething/" + id);

             response.setStatus(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
         }

    }
```

The client (build with the Resteasy Proxy Framework):

```
     ...
     ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
     ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl);

     Resource resource = (Resource) target.proxy(Resource.class);   

     resource.createSomething(anyObject);
     ...
```

How can i retrieve Header information (and others, like Atom Links) which has been  injected by the service?

Is it reasonable to use client side Filters and Interceptors?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution i found was to use a Filter to process the incoming response header.

```
public class HeaderFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {


  private Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

  private List<String> headerFilter = new ArrayList<>();


  public final void addHeaderFilter(final String header) {

      headerFilter.add(header);
  }

  public final void removeHeaderFilter(final String header) {

      headerFilter.remove(header);
  }

  public final String getHeader(final String header) {

      return headers.get(header);
  }

  @Override
  public final void filter(final ClientRequestContext requestContext,
          final ClientResponseContext responseContext) 
                                      throws IOException {

      headers = new HashMap<>();

      for (String headerToLookFor : headerFilter) {

          String header = responseContext.getHeaderString(headerToLookFor);

          if (header != null) {

              headers.put(headerToLookFor, header);
          } else {

              ...
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@ResposeObject can be used for it. It marks interface which will give access to the response. Using annotaions like @Body, @HeaderParam, @Status one can get those parameters from the response. See the examples below.

> a client proxy method returns an interface that represents the information contained in a javax.ws.rs.core.Response. Such an interface must be annotated with @ResponseObject from package org.jboss.resteasy.annotations, and its methods may be further annotated with @Body, @LinkHeaderParam, and @Status from the same package, as well as javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam.

There are some more example in documentation, see here: [Link for the RestEasy documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html)

My example:

```
    @ResponseObject
    public interface MyResponseObject {
    
        @HeaderParam("my_header_name")
        String myHeader();
    
        @Body
        MyBody body();
    }
    
    public class MyBody {        
     List<MyDto> value;
    }


    @Path("test")
    public interface TestClient {
   
       @GET
       MyResponseObject get();
    }
```

Comment: You might want to [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)